# Creating a OssBitString from a std::string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, asn.1, bitstring

The OssBitString takes in string length (in bits) and a const unsigned char* as parameters. However, when I convert the input std::string to const unsigned char* and pass it to OssBitString, the contents of the string get modified and contains weird characters. The following is the conversion function from std::string to OssBitString:

```
inline const OssBitString converter(const std::string&s, int size)
{ 
return OssBitString(size, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()))
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Also,I tried to convert the string into binary format and then convert as a OssBitString as well. But it did not work. How to convert std::string to OssBitString then?

Comment: Should not you address this question to OSS Novalka as you seem to use their ASN1/C++ tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be asking a question about a particular commercial ASN.1 Tool vendor's product, you should send your question directly to them.  To reach OSS Nokalva's technical support, send an email to support@oss.com rather than asking your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Like such:

```
std::string my_str;

OssBitString my_bit_str;

my_bit_str.set(my_str.length(), my_str.data());
```

https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/documentation/asn1_cpp_6.7/asn1cpp-runtime-representation-classes.html#OssBitString_set_length_char

The poor interface of OSS was a good motivator for my to write my own ASN.1 library. In fast_ber any string like type can be assigned to directly. Example of usage in fast_ber:

https://github.com/Samuel-Tyler/fast_ber/blob/master/sample/encode/main.cpp